# Safe to delete .PyCharmCE2017.1 and .PyCharmCE2017.2?

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm 2017.3 just came out so I was wondering if it would be safe to delete .PyCharmCE2017.2 (as well as .PyCharmCE2017.1).  Are there any important files that I need from those or are they all transferred to the newly installed .PyCharmCE2017.3 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: pycharm_import_config]

When you upgrade pycharm, you need to do something above. You can remove the old config dir, as the files in that dir just pycharm settings.